# How OpenMP divide a loop into threads?

Tags: c, optimization, openmp

Say I have a loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    sum += i;
}
```

And if I use OpenMP to speed up it, how is this for loop mapped to 4 different cores?

I know it uses fork and join, I mean is it like i=0 for core 0, i=1 for core 1 and etc or i=0 for core 0, i=249 for core 1, i = 499 for core 2 etc.

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: just check the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP it uses a fork join model

Comment: @pyCthon I know it use fork and join, I mean is it like i=0 for core 0, i=1 for core 1 and etc or i=0 for core 1, i=249 for core 2, i = 499 for core 3 etc.

Comment: @dorafmon see [OpenMP divide for loop over cores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312563/openmp-divide-for-loop-over-cores)

Comment: @Gangadhar Cool thanks I think that answered my question.

Comment: It's such a trivial loop that it cannot sensibly mapped to multiple cores.  Even on the same box, the run time of such a loop is less than the inter-thread comms overhead in queueing it to a pool.

Comment: @MartinJames It is just an example, its not really what I am trying to optimise, instead I am working on a fair complex loop that involve some array index so I am asking this question to see if OpenMP is messing up with cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this presentation](http://sc.tamu.edu/shortcourses/SC-openmp/OpenMPSlides_tamu_sc.pdf)  it depends on the compiler implementation rather than the OpenMP spec, but the compiler would probably use i=0 for core 0, i=249 for core 1, etc.

[image]

Also make sure you are a reduction variable for `sum`, otherwise you have a race condition in your example.